# if $a,b$ such $a^2+b^2+4=2a+ab+2b$,find $a^2b$

Tags: calculus

let $a,b\in R$, and such
$$a^2+b^2+4=2a+ab+2b$$

Find $a^2b=?$

My idea: $$a^2-2a+1+b^2-2b+1+2+ab=0$$
$$(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+ab+2=0$$
then I can't it

maybe this problem   can use inequality to solve it,Than you

Answer (score 7):

The expression can be written as,

$a^2-ab+b^2-2a-2b+4=\frac{3}{4}(a-b)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(a+b-4)^2=0$

Since, $(a-b)^2\ge0$ and $(a+b-4)^2\ge 0$,

So, the only possible real solutions are $a-b=0$ and $a+b-4=0$

That is $a=b=2$.

$a^2b=8$.

Comment: This equation is $a=b=2$,maybe exsit equality methods.Thank you

Comment: and How find this? can you explain?

Comment: $4(a^2 -ab +b^2) = (3a^2-6ab+b^2) +(a^2 +2ab+b^2)=3(a-b)^2 +(a+b)^2$ and also the given expression becomes $\frac{3}{4}(a-b)^2 +\frac{1}{4}(a+b)^2 -2(a+b) +4 = \frac{3}{4}(a-b)^2 +\frac{1}{4}((a+b)^2-8(a+b)+16)=\frac{3}{4}(a-b)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(a+b-4)^2$

Answer (score 4):

other solution: since
$$a^2-(2+b)a+b^2-2b+4=0$$
$$\Delta_{a}=(2+b)^2-4(b^2-2b+4)=-3b^2+12b-12=-3(b^2-4b+4)=-3(b-2)^2\le 0$$
so
$$b-2=0\Longrightarrow b=2\Longrightarrow a=2$$

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the problem as the solution of a quadratic equation in $a$. The solutions are $$a_{\pm}=1+\frac{1}{2} \left(b\pm \sqrt{3} \sqrt{-(b-2)^2}\right)$$ Since $a,b\in R$, $b$ must be equal to $2$; then $a=2$.